# Mobile Friendly HTML in Racket Scribble

Tags: racket, scribble

Given Google's current [mobile friendly policy](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/04/rolling-out-mobile-friendly-update.html), I was wondering if there is a convenient way to generate mobile friendly html output in Racket's [Scribble](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/index.html)?  I understand I could probably hack on the CSS to create one (which sounds like utter hell), but I was wondering if such a thing already exists or is in the works already?

Comment: Can you give an example of some non-mobile friendly output?

Comment: Thanks for your response! By non-mobile friendly, just look at the [Racket docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/). As is Scribble, generates some excellent html, but it's optimized for viewing on large screens. On a smartphone though, you end up having to zoom in and scroll to the right on every page because of the navigation on the left. For what I mean by "mobile friendly," please see [the following](https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/mr-hotel-hotel-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/). Click on the device pictures on the top to see what I'm getting at.

Comment: If the navigation on the left is the only problem, then it is seems you could look into changing the CSS for that element. 

In Chrome you can right click on a page and choose "Inspect". At the left you can now choose to show the page in various resolutions. Try "Responsive" and then experiment with different screen sizes. You will see that elements such as margin notes moves from the margin into the main text. The only element causing problems seems to be the TOC.

Comment: Yep. That's what I was hoping to avoid. I'm guessing that the answer to this question is probably, "no, Scribble does not at this time." Maybe I should put in a [feature request](https://github.com/racket/scribble), because I think this would be a great boon to the community. Do you know if github is the best way to make such a request (since the mailing list seems to be having issues)?

Comment: Try the mailing list. As far as I know it works fine.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks again!